# jQuery setting height of iframe based on if else condition upon click event?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Hi guys I have an iframe that changes in height every time I click on my div with the class "top". The code starts with the deault height of 300 and when I click my div "top" the height drops to 0. However when I click on my div again the height won't go to 300 as I want it to.

JS, CSS and HTML files in order:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".top").click(function(){
            var height = $("#target").height();
            if(height === 300 ){
                $("#target").height(0).slideUp();
            } else{
                $("#target").height(300).slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.top {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
.cb {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cb">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <iframe id="target" src="http://www.disney.com" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

I'm new to jQuery So please advice me how I can implement a slide up and down function too on my iframe so when I click the div it will slide up and down nicely. Thanks and have a great day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if(height = 300)
```

should be

```
 if(height==300)
```

or better yet (check type in addition to value)

```
 if(height===300)
```

Since "height = 300" is an expression, it's assigning a variable named 'height' to 300.  In a conditional statement, this returns true every time.  Here is more information on conditional operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Conditional_(ternary)_operator

Comment: cool, can you please advice me on the sliding up and down effects too. It works now yay!

Comment: Instead of just changing the height, use jQuery's .slideUp() and .slideDown() functions, or .animate() for finer control.

Comment: is it valid to do something like  $("#target").slideup().height(300); ?

Comment: Almost. `.slideUp()` is case sensitive but will hide the element. Change to `sideDown()`. Set the height first. So `$("#target").height(300).slideDown();`

Comment: Thanks v much, great help!

Comment: `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` will open/close `#target` using hide/show, so you don't need to change height anymore, let it to 300. You can also use `slideToggle()` to alternate them, see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/1383/

Comment: If I was using the slide functions, to slide up the iframe I would use  $("#target").height(0).slideUp(time_in_ms); and to slide down would it be   $("#target").height(300).slideDown(time_in_ms);  ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(height == 300 ){
                $("#target").height(0).slideUp(time_in_ms);
```

That should handle the slide up part of your question. I believe your other problem is because the height variable. Try:

```
var height = $("#target").attr('height')
```

Comment: You should update your conditional. When writing a conditional, use "==". A single "=" is an assignment.

Comment: `=` is assignment then return true/false if assignment was successful or not, that's why your target go to 0 then don't change : if condition was always true

Comment: Ok, my slide down part does not work I used $("#target").height(0).slideDown(time_in_ms);